# jQuery select input name inside an iFrame?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I know about the same origin policy, however I wonder if this is possible: I'm having an `iframe` with an src from another website on my site.

Inside of the iframe is input button with `name="sendButton"`, I wonder if i can use jQuery to select this sendButton and on the  onClick an alert should pop up.

Is this possible? Same origin policy?

```
$('input[name=sendButton]').live('click', function(e) {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As far as I know, you are not able to apply jQuery to buttons (or other elements) if it comes from an external source / different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this possible?

No.

> same origin policy?

Yes.